# TypeScript class Date property returns a string

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I've a **model class** in typeScript:

```
export class Season {
    ID: number;
    Start: Date;
}
```

And this is my **component**:

```
export class SeasonsComponent{

seasons: Season[];
selectedSeason: Season;

constructor( 
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private notificationsService: NotificationsService,
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedSeason = new Season();
    this.getSeasons();
}

getSeasons(): void {
    this.configService.getSeasons().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.seasons= response.Data;
            // Data: { Id: 1, Start: '2018-01-01T00:00:00' }
        },
        error => {
            this.notificationsService.show("error", error.error.error, error.error.error_description);
        }
    );
}

selectSeason(season: Season): void {
    this.selectedSeason = season;
}
```

}

**template**:

```
<p-dataList [value]="seasons">
    <ng-template let-season pTemplate="item">
         <div class="ui-g ui-fluid text-capitalize item-list" (click)="selectSeason(season)" 
                            [class.selected]="season === selectedSeason">
                        <div class="ui-md-3 text-center">
                            <div class="pt-4"><h5>{{ season.ID }}</h5></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9">
                            <div class="ui-g">
                                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Start: </div>
                                <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{ season.Start | date: 'MMM d' }}</div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         </ng-template>
    </p-dataList>
    <form class="bg-white p-4" *ngIf="selectedSeason">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                <label>Start</label>
                <p-calendar name="startDate" [required]="true"
                      [ngModel]="selectedSeason?.Start"
                      [inline]="true"
                      [style]="{'max-width': '85%'}">
                </p-calendar>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**And apparently the value of the Start property is  a string** which is causing me problems with a component that requires a Date object as it's ngModel.

If I add this line:

```
this.selectedSeason.Start = new Date(this.selectedSeason.Start);
```

I get:

```
console.log(typeof this.selectedSeason.Start); // object
```

I could just cast it beforehand but then what is the purpose of using types?

Does this have something to do with my class not being fully instantiated or something?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the `Season` instance get created?

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code, which is the code creating the instance of Season and setting the value of its Start property. Remember that at runtime, there is no TypeScript anymore. It's just JavaScript. And JavaScript can assign anything to any variable.

Comment: Ok, so that's the issue. I assumed this.selectedSeason = season would be enough to make sure the properties maintained the type I declared in the class.
So then I'll have to actually create an object (using new?) every time I select a new "Season"?

Comment: No. You would have to make sure that the season passed to seleccionarTemporada, which is supposed to be a Season, is indeed a season. Fix the bug, don't circumvent it. But since you won't tell us where and how this object is created and populated, we can't tell you how to best fix the code.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the post with the full code.

Comment: *what is the purpose of using types?* - type checks during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like that the service return the data transformed, so your service can be like

```
getSeasons()
{
    this.httpClient.get(...).map(result=>{
       //Not return the result, instead return result.Data
       //Moreover, we change all the result.Data to return in Start, a Date Object
       return result.Data.map(d=>{
            Id:d.Id,
            Start:New Date(d.Start)
       }
    }
}
```

Then your component subscribe is like

```
this.configService.getSeasons().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.seasons= response;  //<--just response
        },
        error => {
            this.notificationsService.show("error", error.error.error, error.error.error_description);
        }
    );
```