# How to Strictly specify a return type Angular4/ionic3

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, ionic3

Please I'm trying to specify a particular return type to only include the data that i need from a mongodb server using nodejs.

These are the issues that i'm facing:
 1. the nodejs server always returns an array of json data, which makes it compulsory for me to access the data in ionic3 as indexes(data[0]) instead of dot notation(data.). How can i fix this please ?
 2. the data that's being returned from the database dumps a lot of data back to the client side, I want to filter this data using a typescript interface which i'm importing into the service. I'm going to show an extract of my code in place

ProfileModel interface

```
**(profileModel.ts)**

export interface ProfileModel{
  name : {
            firstName : string,
            lastName : string
    },
    login : {
            username: string
    },

        sex : string,
        address: string,
        status: string,
        coverageArea: string,
        email : string,
        position: string,
        location : {
            latitude: number,
            longitude: number
        }
}
```

The Profile Service Provider function

```
**(profile.ts)**

import { ProfileModel } from './profileModel';
  getMyProfile(data){
    return this.http.get<ProfileModel>(this.apiUrl + data)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))     
  }



  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
      if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
          // A client-side or network error occured
          console.error("An error occured: ", error.error.message)
      } else {
          // The backend returned unsuccessful response
          // The response body may contain clues as to what happened
          console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, `+
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
      }
      return new ErrorObservable("Network Error, please try again later.")
  }
```

Profile Route Server Side Code

```
//Set up
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();

let staffModel = require("../schema");


router.get("/profile/:user", function(req, res){ 
    //let check = req.params();
    staffModel.find({"login.username": req.param("user")})
        .then(data=> {
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            let check = JSON.stringify(data);
            res.send(check);
        })
        .catch(err=> res.send({"error": "There's an issue with the server."}))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Even with these in place, I still get a data dump, that i access with an index and also, it dumps all the unnecessary datas that i don't need from the db

Please any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not use map in your service like I've just posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044223/typescript-class-date-property-returns-a-string/49045110#49045110 ?

Comment: like this:

    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


getMyProfile(data){
 this.http.get<ProfileModel>(this.apiUrl + data)
  .map(result => {
   return result;
  })
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))  
  }

Comment: An interface can't accomplish filtering, an interface doesn't do anything active to your data at all, it merely limits what's considered acceptable to the TypeScript compiler about the syntax of your code. When TypeScript is turned into JavaScript, interfaces disappear completely. Using a map as suggested by Eliseo in the server code can accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3118363 no, not like this. Your map() doesn't do anything. It returns the value you get from the backend as is, without doing any transformation. What it must do is transform the data you obtain from the backedn into the format you want. TypeScript won't do that for you. It's only a compiler.

Comment: so, please how should I do this ?

Comment: `.map(theJsonArrayAsSentByTheServer => transformToProfileModel(theJsonArrayAsSentByTheServer))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use httpClient, NOT http -then you needn't JSON.stringify

if you get an unique value, you can simple

```
//I supouse that you received "data:[{...}]"
getMyProfile(data){
    return this.http.get<ProfileModel>(this.apiUrl + data)
    .map(result=>{  //don't return result, just result.data[0]
       return result.data[0];
    })
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))     
  }
```

If you get an array -several data-, you can

```
// data:[{...},{...}]
getMyProfile(data){
    return this.http.get<ProfileModel>(this.apiUrl + data)
    .map(result=>{  //don't return result, just result.data
       return result.data 
    })
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))     
  }
```

MoreOver you can transform the array

```
// data:[{id:0,val:'aaa',val2:'bbb'},{id:1,val:'ccc',val2:'ddd'}]
getMyProfile(data){
    return this.http.get<ProfileModel>(this.apiUrl + data)
    .map(result=>{                 //don't return result, just result.data
                                   //but, transform the data
       return result.data.map(d=>{ //e.g. I don't want "val2"
           id:d.id,
           val:d.val
       }) 
    })
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))     
  }
```

Comment: Yea, Yea, Yea! Thanks a billion. 

Thumbs up

Comment: @user3118363 - On StackOverflow, the best way to give thumbs up is to upvote the answer, in addition to marking it as accepted.

Comment: I marked it as accepted, but i can't find the upvote button or anything like that, can you help me locate that ?

Comment: i think i got it. the upward arrow by the left. got it and done it